# Angular Page refresh is not working for $route.reload() and $state.go() and transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a credit card info iframe which runs on top of the angular web and selected based on the drop down and captured all the credit card information.  After entering all the data when I'm clicking next it'll successfully navigate to the next page. But as per my design, when it enter any credit card data and press next it should populate in the drop down. Currently, this happens once I reload the page only.

I used:

```
$state.go('checkout', { reload: true }); / 
$state.reload($state.current.name);
```

but it's not working, even the transition not working. is there any workaround for this.

I just want to click next and come back by clicking back button to see my drop down contain my credit card number.

Comment: is there any javascript error in your console?

Comment: You can use `rootScope.your creditCardDetails` . After adding credit cards details push data to `rootScope` so that it will be visible as and when u add

Comment: I think the best answer would be $state.go('checkout', { }, { reload: true }); . This is not a good practice but make sure to clear the cache to depend on the browser you used this scripts.

Comment: @AgamBanga , no there's no Console errors in my app. Thanks for the heads up .